# How to pass an entire typecsript Enum as a component input on Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, generics, enums

I have a generic component that receives a `Enum` as input:

```js
TableComponent<Columns> {

    @Input() columnsEnum: Columns;
}
```

The `Enum` looks like this:

```js
export enum CardsEnum {
    CODE = 'sCode',
    NAME = 'sName',
    ID = 'sId'
}
```

And on my holder template, I have an instance of `table-component` as this:

```js
<table-component [columnsEnum]="cardsEnum"></table-component>
```

And on my `.ts` of the holder component, I have a refererence to the `Enum`:

```js
cardsEnum = CardsEnum
```

Angular infer the type of `Columns` properly, setting this to be `CardsEnum`. The problem is that on the template where I'm instantiating `table-component`, I receive the following error on the input:

```sh
Type 'typeof CardsEnum' is not assignable to type 'CardsEnum'.
```

And that's true, If I look to my holder component, the type that my variable stores is `typeof CardsEnum`, not `CardsEnum`:

```js
(property) HolderComponent.cardsEnum: typeof CardsEnum
```

I can bypass the error setting `cardsEnum = CardsEnum as unknown as CardsEnum` but I don't want to do that.

I can't import the `Enum` directly on `table-component` because I'm going to pass different enums to this component, since its a generic component and that's my goal.

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Comment: Setting type of the `TableComponent.columnsEnum` to`unknown` will "fix" the error but probably won't really help you. The answer depends on how exactly are you planning to work with the enums in the component.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll ultimately want to iterate on that enum to display your columns. Could it make sense to simply convert your enum into an array beforehand ?
`let columns: Array<string> = Object.values(CardsEnum);`